# How to resolve 'ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence' error?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am facing 'ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence' error as a value for 'P_RESPONSE' cursor. It doesn't matter if select query returns any records, error is there in the output every single time.
Please note that 'REQUESTSUBMITTERS.USERNAME' is a primary key.

PFB Stored Procedure.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_REQUESTSUBMITTER (
    P_USERNAME         IN   REQUESTSUBMITTERS.USERNAME%TYPE,
    P_RESPONSE         OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR,
    SPRESULT           OUT  VARCHAR2,
    SPRESPONSECODE     OUT  VARCHAR2,
    SPRESPONSEMESSAGE  OUT  VARCHAR2
)
AS
    L_REQUESTSUBMITTER  REQUESTSUBMITTERS%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN P_RESPONSE FOR
    SELECT USERNAME, GEN, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAILID, OFFICELOCATION, TITLE, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT
        FROM REQUESTSUBMITTERS 
        WHERE UPPER(USERNAME)=UPPER(P_USERNAME);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN P_RESPONSE%NOTFOUND;
        FETCH P_RESPONSE INTO L_REQUESTSUBMITTER;  
    END LOOP;
    IF P_RESPONSE%ROWCOUNT=0 THEN
        OPEN P_RESPONSE FOR
            SELECT 'NA' AS USERNAME FROM DUAL;
        SPRESULT:='NOK';
        SPRESPONSECODE:='GETREQSUBMTR-002';
        SPRESPONSEMESSAGE:=CONCAT('SUBMITTER RECORD NOT FOUND FOR USER - ', P_USERNAME);
    ELSE
        SPRESULT:='OK';
        SPRESPONSECODE:='GETREQSUBMTR-001';
        SPRESPONSEMESSAGE:=CONCAT('SUBMITTER RECORD FOUND FOR USER - ', P_USERNAME);
    END IF;

END GET_REQUESTSUBMITTER;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your EXIT statement should be after the FETCH statement inside the loop, else you'll loop past the end.

Don't forget to CLOSE the cursor.

Comment: Result remains same even if I write EXIT statement after the FETCH statement inside the loop. Also, when I added 'CLOSE P_RESPONSE;' statement just before 'END;' statement, stored procedure stopped returning output.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes and see if your procedure works

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE GET_REQUESTSUBMITTER (
        P_USERNAME         IN   REQUESTSUBMITTERS.USERNAME%TYPE,
        P_RESPONSE         OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR,
        SPRESULT           OUT  VARCHAR2,
        SPRESPONSECODE     OUT  VARCHAR2,
        SPRESPONSEMESSAGE  OUT  VARCHAR2
    )
    AS
        L_REQUESTSUBMITTER  REQUESTSUBMITTERS%ROWTYPE;
    L_ROW_CNT NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        OPEN P_RESPONSE FOR
        SELECT USERNAME, GEN, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAILID, OFFICELOCATION, TITLE, MANAGER, DEPARTMENT
            FROM REQUESTSUBMITTERS 
            WHERE UPPER(USERNAME)=UPPER(P_USERNAME);
        LOOP
            FETCH P_RESPONSE INTO L_REQUESTSUBMITTER; 
            EXIT WHEN P_RESPONSE%NOTFOUND;  
        END LOOP;
        L_ROW_CNT:= P_RESPONSE%ROWCOUNT;  
        CLOSE P_RESPONSE;    
        IF L_ROW_CNT=0 THEN
            OPEN P_RESPONSE FOR
                SELECT 'NA' AS USERNAME FROM DUAL;
            SPRESULT:='NOK';
            SPRESPONSECODE:='GETREQSUBMTR-002';
            SPRESPONSEMESSAGE:=CONCAT('SUBMITTER RECORD NOT FOUND FOR USER - ', P_USERNAME);
        CLOSE P_RESPONSE;  
        ELSE
            SPRESULT:='OK';
            SPRESPONSECODE:='GETREQSUBMTR-001';
            SPRESPONSEMESSAGE:=CONCAT('SUBMITTER RECORD FOUND FOR USER - ', P_USERNAME);
        END IF;

    END GET_REQUESTSUBMITTER;
```